# CSS Grayscale to a certain color palette an svg

Tags: css, tags

I want to hover an svg with a diferent set of colors after grayscaling that svg.
There is any way of setting a certain color palette to an svg with a filter css or an math algorithm?

Im not any expert in color manupulation so any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through CSS filters or through SVG filters. SVG filters are probably the more technically complex solution.

You can try playing with the `hue-rotate` function on the example on this page: [filter in MDN CSS Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

You can combine more than one function, in different orders too, to get different results.

Keep in mind that you won't get far if you set `grayscale` to `100%` or `saturate` to `0%` as your first function, as you wipe out the hue info and you can't recolorize (at least not through CSS IIRC).

Try playing with `hue-rotate`, `brightness`, `contrast`, `invert`, or even combining them.

Also keep in mind that most of the functions are set in percentage units, but `hue-rotate` is in degrees of the color wheel (deg).